# Readability API

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I want to use [readability parser API](https://www.readability.com/developers/api) but when I am making call to this API I am getting blank/no response.

When I tried with some other url the same code is giving proper response.

```
<html>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8;"> 
   <head>
      <script language="javascript">
         var getJSON = function(url, successHandler, errorHandler) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('get', url, true);
            alert("-------" + url);
            //xhr.responseType = 'json';
            xhr.onload = function() {
               var status = xhr.status;
               alert("===========" + status);
               if (status == 200) {
                  successHandler && successHandler(xhr.response);
               } else {
                  errorHandler && errorHandler(status);
               }
            };
            xhr.send();
         };

         function getReading() {
            var url1 = "https://www.readability.com/api/content/v1/parser?url=";
            var testurl = "http://www.saptechnical.com/Tutorials/WebDynproABAP/ALV/page1.htm";
            var urltoken = "&token=tokenkeyhere";
            var finalurl = url1 + testurl + urltoken;
            alert(finalurl);
            getJSON(finalurl, function(data) {
               alert(data.domain);
            });
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input type="button" value="go" onClick="getReading()" />
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your JavaScript console?

Comment: No I am not getting any errors. Earlier it was showing me error about localhost, that you can not make a call to API from localhost, so I changes settings in IIS and assigned a domain name. But now no errors still I am not able to get output. But Yes in Crome I am getting Error " No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access." Mozilla have no such errors. Please help me on this. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got answer and code is working now..
I used getJSON method to make a call to API.

```
function getInfo() {
    var url = $("#txtSubmitlink").val();
        $.getJSON("https://www.readability.com/api/content/v1/parser?url="+ url +"&token=tokenkeyhere&callback=?",
        function (data) {
            $("#dvContent").html(data.content);
            $("#imgLeadImage").attr('src', data.lead_image_url);
        });
    }
```

Thanks everyone-